# Add random number as query parameter to avoid caching with Chrome extension?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, url-rewriting, requestly

Is there a way to add the current timestamp as query parameters?
I think it could be useful to avoid any cache issue.

Originally Asked here - https://twitter.com/tcoppin_/status/1209131288965341190

Answer (score 0):

Requestly supports `rq_rand(X)` as a predefined function which can be used to add a random number with X number of digits when you do a URL rewrite.

For example - Suppose you want to add a random number to all Javascript URLs matching www.example.com, you can set up a `Modify QueryParams Rule` like this -

[image]

**Note - If you add cache buster to all URLs, it might make your browsing a bit slow so you can add additional filters if you intend to add cache buster query param to only particular resources**

Here's an example of setting up filters for matching a Rule

[image]

This can be really helpful in web development to avoid caching especially when using webpack bundles.